# Address of segment descriptor

Tags: operating-system, registry

All values ​​are in hexadecimal number system.  On Pentium in protected mode, registers have the following value: `LDTR = 06000000, GDTR = 08000000, CR3 = 10000000, DS = 14, CS = 0034 CR0 = 00000001`.
If the instruction (e.g. `MOV AL, [2A66]` accesses the logical address 2A66, what physical address does it access? At what address is the segment descriptor located? Current memory status, looking at absolute addresses is:

```
........
06000000 CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A EE FE 1D F0 4F 03 22 05 8A 03
06000010 22 05 17 03 22 93 0D 04 01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF
.........
08000000 CA 20 FF 9F 00 9A E3 FE 1D F2 4F 08 23 05 8A 07
08000010 26 05 19 03 22 05 0D 04 01 02 01 00 02 FF FA FF
.........
10000020 3A 56 21 40 2A 38 42 18 2A 56 42 40 8E 48 42 18
10000030 2A 36 42 40 9A 48 42 18 7A 56 42 20 8E 48 42 18
10000040 23 60 42 40 4E A8 42 18 5A 56 42 40 8E 48 42 18
.........
40426860 C6 06 23 99 00 80 3E 1D 96 00 74 03 E9 99 00 E8
40426870 A6 01 E8 FF 03 75 19 80 3E C4 98 00 34 00 AD 0A
40426880 13 96 00 BA E9 89 75 03 E9 17 01 C6 06 1F 99 01
40426890 B8 00 6C BE 08 98 BB 21
.........
C6011D70 C6 06 23 99 00 80 3E 1D 96 00 74 03 E9 99 00 E8
C6011D80 A6 01 E8 FF 03 75 19 80 3E C4 98 00 34 00 AD 0A
C6011D90 13 96 00 BA E9 89 75 03 E9 17 01 C6 06 1F 99 01
```

Could you give me some guidelines what is the problem here and what I need to know to solve it? Operating systems and registry is new to me, so I don't know what I'm supposed to do here. I don't know even where should I start.

Comment: Where did you get this problem? Just a sidenote but normally "registries" is termed registers.

Comment: It seems like a simple problem but it is rare that people just learn the meaning of all control register's bits so it would require looking that up and also looking up the gdt and its fields. Then looking at memory and finding out the answer. If you got this problem at school, you probably have a textbook?

Comment: yes, I got this problem at university and I have a textbook, but I don't know how to find this. Could you post briefly explanation how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: @user123 could you post any example for solving this?

Comment: The problem gives CR3. Yet, bit 32 (paging) of CR0 is disabled. Do you have the answer to the problem? It doesn't even seem consistent. Unless it is an intended trap.

Comment: I don't have answer, it's homework. Any answer would help me.